# Can't get a remote form to refresh a div

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app with an internal complaint form  . When I am in the edit mode, I want to be able to show, delete and add users to that complaint.

Using a partial to show the users assigned to the complaint works.

The delete link next to each user works. When I click on a link, the user is deleted from the document_histories table and the div with the assigned users partial is refreshed.

If I click on the link to add a user, I have a pop up window. The user or users  is/are added to the assigned users (Document_histories) table. However, I cannot get the partial to refresh as it does when a user is deleted.

I have a button that will cause a refresh but that isn't good from a usability perspective. I need to have the div/partial automatically refresh when a user is added.

The thing I can't get to work is to have the div/partial refresh after the form for adding a user to the complaint closes.

My complaints/edit.html.erb has

```
    <%= link_to( '<button>Refresh the assigned users list</button>'.html_safe,
                   #,
                   remote: true,
                   controller: 'document_histories',
                   action: 'new',
          ) %> <br>  # This will manually refresh the partial showing users assigned to the complaint - I want this to happen when the assign users form closes. 


     <%= link_to( '<button>assign a user</button>'.html_safe,
                   "/document_histories/new",
                   'data-popup' => true,
                   remote: true,
                   :class => "button_class",
                   :onclick=>"window.open(this.href,'assign complaint to users', 'height=800, width=500');
                                    script.src= 'create.js.erb';
                                    return false;"
          ) %>  #pops up a new window to add user to complaint(document_histories table)


  <div id="refresh_assigned">
         <% if @document_histories.count > 0 then %>
            <%= render :partial => '/document_histories/history_for_complaint_form', controller: 'document_histories', action: 'new' %>
        <% else %>
            <h4> There is no document history at this time.. </h4>
        <% end %>
      </div>
    </td>

<%= render 'form' %>  # renders the complaint(edit) form
```

My document_histories/new controller is

```
  def new
    @document_history = DocumentHistory.new
    @document_histories = DocumentHistory.all
    @users = User.uniq.pluck(:name)

    @existing_sent_to = DocumentHistory.where(:complaint_id => $document_assign)

    @existing_sent_to.each do |remove_existing|   #removes users already assigned from the dropdown
        @users.delete(remove_existing.sent_to)
    end

    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render :new }
        format.js {}
        #format.json { render json: @document_history.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
```

The new.js.erb is

```
$('#refresh_assigned').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'document_histories/history_for_complaint_form')).html_safe %>");
alert("new 123");
```

I put the alert box in to see when the code is executing. When I click on the assign users link, I see the alert and the assigned users list is refreshed. I do NOT see the alert when submitting the assign a user form. The assigned user is added to the document_histories table as expected. However, the partial is not updated until I use the refresh button to manually update it.

My document_histories/create is

```
   respond_to do |format|
        #  if @document_history.save  ## We can probably drop these lines since the create above seems to take the place of a save
        #   format.html { redirect_to @document_history, notice: 'Complaint Assignment was successful' }
        #  format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @document_history }
        #  end

     format.js { render :file => "/document_histories/create.js.erb" }

     # format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @document_history }
         if no_email   || $email_address_error                                                               # if a user was encountered that did not have an email address, show a message



           format.html { render :text => '<script type="text/javascript">
                                         alert("IMPORTANT NOTE - At least one of the users you assigned this complaint to did not have an email address or their email address was invalid. \n \n This can usually be corrected by having the user log on to this application. \n \n If the problem persists, please contact IT");
                                          window.close()
  script.src= "\document_histories\create.js.erb";
                                          </script>' }
         #  format.js   { render :file => "/document_histories/create.js.erb" }

         else                                                                         # otherwise show a standard message

           format.html { render :text => '<script type="text/javascript">
                                          alert(" The users you selected have been assigned to this complaint. \n \n This window will close when you press OK");
                                          window.close()
  script.src= "\document_histories\create.js.erb";
                                          </script>'
           }

         end
```

I have an create.js.erb with an alert letting me know if it executed. That does not seem to be executing.

My goal is to have the refresh_assigned partial to refresh after I add a user to the complaint.

Comment: nitpicking sidenote: <a> containing a <button> is not a valid html(5) https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

Comment: It would be useful to see code of the view rendering the pop-up window, too.